# Making less's follow option show line movement

Tags: tail, less

I often find myself using less to display log files that contain hundreds of
contiguous, identical lines that are appended to the files at set intervals.

For example,

```
something happened
something happened
something happened
something happened
something happened
something happened
something happened
... (100 identical lines later)
something happened
something happened
```

I use less's follow option to follow the log file, but once a certain number of
identical lines have been printed, it is impossible to tell if the log file is
still being written to.

Using `tail` with the `-f` flag solves this problem by allowing me to put
newlines in with its output, which float along with the text, showing the
text's flow/movement.

```
$ tail -f a-terrible-log-file   |   (a few seconds later)
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened<C-j>         |   something happened
                                |   something happened                        
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened      
something happened              |   something happened
```

Is there a way to show line flow/movement in `less`?

Comment: Could you paste the full `less` command you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start less with `-N` to show Line-Numbers.